# Azure App Service .net6 Deploy - Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/home/site/wwwroot/wwwroot/Identity/lib/bootstrap/LICENSE'

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, duende-identity-server

I updated my Asp.net core Blazor WebAssembly app to .net 6. Everything is fine, but the deploy from github actions doesn't work and throws this error:

```
...
Copying file: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.dll'
Copying file: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.dll'
Omitting next output lines...
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/home/site/wwwroot/wwwroot/Identity/lib/bootstrap/LICENSE'
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
Kudu Sync failed
\n/opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh "/home/site/deployments/tools/deploy.sh"
Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Error: Deployment Failed with Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
```

What could be a problem here?

- app works on local
- I updated the azure app to .net6 in configuration
- I tried to restart the app
- the app is in Central US region

**EDIT/SOLUTION**:

Previously the path to licence file was: `/home/site/wwwroot/wwwroot/Identity/lib/bootstrap/LICENSE/LICENSE` new file was without the `LICENSE` dir. So when the new version of app arrived it tried to update the LICENSE file, which was actually a directory. Removing `LICENSE/LICENSE` helped.

Answer (score 8):

I ended up deleting the contents of /home/site/wwwroot/ to resolve this as well. I also needed to update the configuration to .NET 6 in the site's configuration and redeploy before my site started working.

Comment: Removing the LICENSE directory and file would also seem to be enough to get around this issue too.  It's a very annoying issue, and there seems to be no documentation from MS about it and i guess lots of people will be doing this update for .net6 from now on.

Comment: Worked for me when switched from .NET6 to .NET6 Isolated with Azure functions

Comment: "Update the configuration" .. I think it would help if you mentioned what you updated

Comment: In Azure portal, select the web app. Under the Settings header, choose Configuration. Under the General Settings heading, and under Stack settings, ensure the Stack is set to .NET, and Major version is .NET 6 and Minor version is .NET 6 (LTS). Save the configuration which will restart the web app.

Comment: Yes, seems that the EF Core distributables (which adds the Identity folder to the wwwroot) changed the structure between .NET 5 (and earlier) and .NET 6 (and later) such that the deploy was trying to write a folder as if it were a file. Deleting the folder and letting it get recreated worked fine and should be a one-time thing.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was some rogue Thumbs.db file (nasty little files that are hidden). I had to log in to FTP /home/site/wwwroot/, delete everything in this folder. Then some folders wouldn't delete. So I had to turn on "Server -> Force Show Hidden Files" in filezilla. Then I could see thumbs.db and delete it.. I also had to remove all Thumbs.db from my project, and repo, then redeploy.