# Cannot deploy Azure app service via GitHub Actions after upgrading from .NET Core 5 to 6

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0, kudu

I updated my ASP.NET Core web application from .NET Core 5 to .NET Core 6. This seems to work fine locally.

I then checked my changes into GitHub, whereupon a GitHub action builds and deploy this to my App Service on Azure. This did not work the first time, because my YAML file still referenced .NET 5. I changed that and tried again. However, I then got a different error:

> Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/home/site/wwwroot/wwwroot/Identity/lib/bootstrap/LICENSE'

I found a post describing this very error and attempted to follow the instructions suggested by Trevor Davis (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70136206/98422), which was to delete the contents of the /home/site/wwwroot/ folder in my deployed App Service and re-deploy.

However, having done so, I now get a different error when trying to deploy the website:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/site/wwwroot/Azure.Storage.Blobs.dll'
>
> An error has occurred during web site deployment.
>
> Kudu Sync failed

...and now I've no idea how to fix it. And my website is down :-(

Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I hope this helps someone else. I discovered that simply stopping the website while the deploy was in progress was enough to make it work again.

Two days needless downtime... :-(

Answer (score 0):

I removed all references to identity as I wasn't using it, this got the deployment working. Not sure why..

Answer (score 0):

I my situation, the underlying issue seemed to be updating Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI from version 5.* to version 6+. What worked for me was just reverting Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI to 5.0.17.

Comment: @JiffyLeub Did you manage to get your website to successfully deploy with a .Net 6.0 version of the AspNetCore.Identity packages installed?

Comment: @Goober I have not. I tried a few solutions mentioned in other SO threads, but nothing yet has worked.