# Github Actions fails to deploy AspDotNetCore MVC 6.0 to Azure App Service Linux but says Deployment Successful

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-identity, github-actions, .net-6.0

- I have an Asp.Net Core MVC 6.0 application.
- It contains multiple class library projects.
- It is also running Asp.Net Identity.
- The project is also hosted in a Github repository.

The application builds and runs fine locally, however, I have added a Github Action for deploying the website to an Azure App Service Linux box, and whilst the deployment says it was successful, the website never gets deployed to Azure.

**Here is the website running fine locally:**

[image]

**Here is the Github Action deployment status:**

[image]

**Here is the Azure App Service page, following the "successful" deployment status on Github Actions:**

[image]

**Additional Information**

I can also see that [an issue has been opened here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71295965/cannot-deploy-azure-app-service-via-github-actions-after-upgrading-from-net-cor) whereby the user reports that the issue was to do with Asp.Net Identity, and that they had to downgrade the version from .Net 6 to .Net 5, to get it to deploy successfully.

**Questions:**

1. Does anyone have any insights into why this isn't working?
2. How do I debug this scenario?

**UPDATE 1:**

Following some debugging, I can see that the secret I created on Github Actions (which stores the publishing profile for the Azure Web App Service Server , is actually blank, despite me adding the secret value multiple times).

[image]

Is this a bug in Github? Does anyone else have the same problem?

**UPDATE 2:**

- I have visited the KUDU site for the azure app service (https://houseplatform.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui).
- I then checked the contents under the ../site/wwwroot and I can see that there is no file named hostingstart.html (but there a lot of DLLs for all the class library projects from the source code).

Here is my YAML file:

```
name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to an Azure Web App

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: house-platform-dev    # set this to the name of your Azure Web App
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.'      # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  DOTNET_VERSION: '6.0'                 # set this to the .NET Core version to use

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v2
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }}
      
      - name: Set up dependency caching for faster builds
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ~/.nuget/packages
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-nuget-${{ hashFiles('**/packages.lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-nuget-
      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release

      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

  deploy:
    permissions:
      contents: none
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Development'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your app service name is `HousePlatform`, please follow my steps to troubleshoot the issue. If you provide more details, I also will update this answer.

**Steps:**

1. Go to the kudu site via the link : https://HousePlatform.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui
2. Check the contents under the `../site/wwwroot`.

   [image]

   [image]

   [image]
3. If it's empty or just have a `hostingstart.html` file like my sample picture, it means deploy failed. We need to check the `.yml` file, you can find it under the `.github/workflows` in github repo.
4. If the contents under the `../site/wwwroot` like locals, it means it deployed successfully. Then we can move to step 5.
5. Navigate to `Configuration`, click the General settings, then find `Startup Command`. We can [refer the official doc to add the startup command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/faqs-app-service-linux#what-are-the-expected-values-for-the-startup-file-section-when-i-configure-the-runtime-stack-).

   [image]

Comment: I've provided an update which explains that there was no hostingstart.html file present in the KUDU site. Thoughts?

Comment: @Goober You misunderstood me, the hostingstart.html file is created when creating a new app service, and when we perform a publishing operation, this file may be deleted (if you check Delete the original file when publishing, the original publish file will be deleted).

Comment: @Goober Luckily, the files have been published successfully, which is why you can see a lot of dll files, please follow my answer, add startup command.